# Show tags when improving a suggested edit on an answer, not just question

Tags: feature-request, tags, suggested-edits, improve-edit

Today I was improving a suggested edit on another site to correct some spelling errors and add in some more information for better clarity. However when I was in the edit screen, the tags were not present which would have been helpful for getting the information I needed to improve the edit. When I went back to get the information I lost the ability to complete the review.

It would be a great help to show all tags on the suggested edits queue when improving an edit. This is already the case for questions, but not for answers.

As you can see on the initial screen it shows what tags the post has but it does not once you start improving it.

The screen shots are from Board & Card Games which is currently in beta.

Suggested edit review, with the tag present: (even though it's an answer)

> [image]

And when choosing to improve, no tags are present:

> [image]

Can this please be made consistent, so that tags are always showing?

Comment: @nicael The site I was editing on has a low rate for suggested edits, lucky it was there for me again when I went back.

Comment: @JoeW I see the tags field when improving: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CSHTQ.png... Am I missing something??

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Those tags are clearly no present in the screenshot I posted.